# How is the facebook ticker design implemented?

Tags: html, css, facebook

I know the backend detail,that it works using long polling.
I am more interested in knowing how the sidebar is persistent through different pages.

The sidebar is not being loaded again,when a new link is created.How could this be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the link clicks with Javascript. Once you get a click, you would only change the main content (whatever the main `div` or block is) and keep the sidebar intact. So, it's kind of like "pseudo-links." I don't think you actually go to another page, but the content of the current page is changed.

[Handling URL change with Javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956710/handle-url-change-by-javascript)

[How to change the URL in the browser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/how-do-i-with-javascript-change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new) (Facebook changes the address bar URL without actually loading the page.)